# How to get the name of uploaded file on server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use "File Uploading Class" of CodeIgniter to upload files; my problem is later on I'm using the uploaded image name and although I already used  the following code to give the meaning full name, Users may have already saved the same name and the new file will be like "John1","John2", "John3",...

```
        ...
        $config['file_name'] = $this->input->post("employeeName");
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

Is there any way to figure out the real name which was used to save the file with the added extensions?

I hope my questions is clear, but if you need more clarification, please just let me know which part you need more clarification.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`$this->upload->data()` will return an assoc array of everything about the file, after it has been uploaded:

Sample output:

```
Array
(
    [file_name]    => mypic.jpg
    [file_type]    => image/jpeg
    [file_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/
    [full_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/jpg.jpg
    [raw_name]     => mypic
    [orig_name]    => mypic.jpg
    [client_name]  => mypic.jpg
    [file_ext]     => .jpg
    [file_size]    => 22.2
    [is_image]     => 1
    [image_width]  => 800
    [image_height] => 600
    [image_type]   => jpeg
    [image_size_str] => width="800" height="200"
)
```

Full documentation here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: Thanks man! You solved it! I have to wait 9 minutes to accept your solution :)